# Differentiability of a coefficient function

Tags: differential-geometry

do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* writes

[image]

My question is that why $\lambda(t)$ is differentiable? As the proposition says, $-\lambda(t)$ is the principal curvature along $\alpha'(t)$, hence the corresponding principal curvature $\kappa_1(t)$ is differentiable. If we take a local coordinate to compute the principal curvatures, we will have
$$ \kappa_{1,2} = H\pm \sqrt{H^2 - K} $$ where $K$ and $H$ are Gaussian curvature and mean curvature, respectively. Then it may not be differentiable if $H^2=K$, i.e., the principal curvatures may not be differentiable at umbilical points.

Comment: Assuming the parametrization is regular, $\lambda(t) = \langle N'(t),\alpha'(t)\rangle/|\alpha'(t)|^2$ is the  quotient of a differentiable function by a non-zero differentiable function and thus differentiable.

Comment: Yes, but that's assuming a lot. For a non-regular parameterization allows a curve to "turn a corner" at a place where $\alpha'(t) = 0$, resulting in $C$ not being a line of curvature. For instance, in the plane, one can parameterized a square in that way, but a square is certainly not a line of curvature. Of course, in this theorem the regularity of $C$ ensures that this particular case doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misreading. Let me rewrite the "sufficient" part:

A sufficient condition for ... is that there be a parametrization $\alpha$ of $C$, and a differentiable function $\lambda$ such that 
$$
N'(t) = \lambda(t) \alpha'(t),
$$
where $N(t) = N(\alpha(t))$.

In other words, the requirement is that there be SOME parameterization $\alpha$ for which the resulting scale-factor is differentiable. There's always some other paramterization for which this is *not* true -- simply compose $\alpha$ with a non-differentiable function from $R$ to $R$, for instance -- something like $t = s^\frac{1}{3}$.